# Scripting out the installation of Team City agents

Tags: automated-install, teamcity

We have a reasonable-sized Team City installation and currently I am planning to add another 25 agents, 5 agents per machine. So far I was doing the installation manually:

1. Log into the server
2. Download and run `agentInstaller.exe`, add the agent number to the name
3. Open a command prompt as administrator and run the script to install the service (given a service name with the agent number appended)
4. Open the `Services` configuration settings, change the user that the service is running as and start the service

Is there a simple way to script as many of these steps as possible? Ideally I would like to log into the box, and run a single script with agent number to do steps 2-4.

Answer (score 3):

How about making [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/TeamCityAgent) do this:

```
cinst TeamCityAgent -params 'serverurl=http://servername:8081 agentName=Build1'
```

It seems that you still have to open firewall ports, though. This is from Asger Hallas's comment in the link above:

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Allow TeamCity" -Direction Inbound -Protocol TCP -LocalPort 9090 -Program "c:\program files\java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -Action Allow
```

The [installation of Chocolatey itself](https://chocolatey.org/) is a PowerShell one-liner, too:

```
iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

I have yet to find a way for a scripted installation of the TeamCity *server*, though.

Comment: That looks promising, where can I find the documentation (i.e. list of options) for this package?

Comment: @Grzenio: If you click the "Show" link (close to "tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1") on [the TeamCity package page](https://chocolatey.org/packages/TeamCityAgent), it shows the source code of the installation routine. In particular, you can see that `serverUrl`, `agentDir`, `agentName` and `ownPort` are valid options. I'm not sure if there's better documentation than that.

Comment: @Grzenio: Did this work for you?

Comment: You can do the server, but you need to use some PowerShell to submit the administrator password and database type pages. There is an Azure template I've seen for deploying TeamCity Server in this manner.